# Set input textbox value from another model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a html select field. I want to use the selecteditems pid attribute as a input textbox's default value. I tried the following two ways

My select field

```
<select ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-options="product.pname for product in products"></select>
```

**Way 1:**

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="neworder.pid" ng-init="neworder.pid={{selectedProduct.pid}}" required />
```

**Way 2:**

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="neworder.pid" required />
```

and in controller

```
$scope.neworder.pid = $scope.selectedProduct.pid
```

But failed to make both of them work. How to do it correctly?

**Update**

My form containing the select field.

```
<form name="addOrder" data-ng-show="addMode" style="width:600px;margin:0px auto;">
        <select ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-options="product.pname for product in products"></select>
        {{selectedProduct.pid}}
        <label>PID:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="neworder.pid" ng-init="neworder.pid={{selectedProduct.pid}}" required />
        <label>OID:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="neworder.oid" required />
        <label>QTY:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="neworder.qty" required />
        <label>TOTAL:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="neworder.total" required />
        <br />
        <!-- <span class="error" data-ng-show="addCustomer.$error.required">Required!</span>-->
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" data-ng-click="add()" data-ng-disabled="!addOrder.$valid" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <br /><br />
    </form>
```

add function in controller

```
$scope.add = function () {
            $http.post('/api/OrderDetails/', this.neworder).success(function (data) {
                alert("Added Successfully!!");
                $scope.addMode = false;
                $scope.orders.push(data);
            }).error(function (data) {
                $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding product! " + data;

            });
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just bind to the `selectedProduct`?

Like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedProduct.pid" name="pid">
```

This works as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K7FNn/).

**Edit**

Use `ng-change` like so:

```
<select ng-options="..." ng-change="newOrder.pid=selectedProduct.pid" ng-model="..."></select>
```

and

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newOrder.pid">
```

Comment: because i need the model name to be 'neworder.pid' so that I can use all the form values in my controller by using `this.neworder` later on. I added my form so you can have a look.

Comment: so use `ng-change` with a function which sets `neworder.pid` to `selectedProduct.pid`. that should work

Answer (score 1):

$http.get(*some text here*)
    .success(function(*some text here*) {

```
$scope.neworder ={name of your input field: 'text you want to show inside input field'};

    });
```

Just Remember, you have to write this inside $http.get() function, as it will fetch the value before entering into it from the user